# Why two !!s in an IF statement when using &&?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

I'm looking through some code and see an IF statement that looks like the one below. Can anyone tell me why there are two !!s instead of one? I've never seen this before and can't dig anything up on Google because it's ignoring the special character.

```
if (!!myDiv && myDiv.className == 'visible') {
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double not operator is used to cast a variable to the `boolean` type. The dobule nots cancel each other out, but seeing as `!` returns `true` or `false`, you only get one of the two output.

For example,

```
!!0 == true
```

So

```
!!myDiv == true
```

Casts `myDiv` to a boolean and tests it against true. `!!myDiv` will only give `true` or `false`.

Comment: Wow, that's cool. Dug up this link based on Jam's answer. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1784-Using-Double-Not-Operator-For-Boolean-Type-Casting.htm

Comment: Why is this even necessary in the example given in the question? The predicate of an `if` condition is already interpreted as a boolean. Also, `!!0 !== true`, since `0` is falsy.

Answer (score 0):

The double-bang (`!!`) converts the value to a true boolean. The first bang "not's" the potentially truthy/falsy value to a proper boolean and the second "not's" it back to what the value should be as a proper boolean.

Answer (score 0):

`!!` will coerce any object into a Boolean. It will evaluate to true for non-falsy values. But its not magic, its just a double not.

```
          !!false === false
           !!true === true

              !!0 === false
!!parseInt("foo") === false // NaN is falsy
              !!1 === true
             !!-1 === true  // -1 is truthy

             !!"" === false // empty string is falsy
          !!"foo" === true  // non-empty string is truthy
        !!"false" === true  // ...even if it contains a falsy value

     !!window.foo === false // undefined is falsy
           !!null === false // null is falsy

             !!{} === true  // an (empty) object is truthy
             !![] === true  // an (empty) array is truthy; PHP
```

Answer (score 0):

- `&` is a bitwise comparion (resulting in a value >= 0).
- `&&` is a logical comparision (resulting in true or false).
- `=` is assignment (always evaluates as true).
- `==` is a logical comparison (resulting in true or false).

Comment: You haven't answered the question...

Comment: Yeah, silly me, I realised that as soon as I hit "Post" :P

Answer (score 0):

!!myDiv means twice the operator ! (equals to not).

myDiv seems to be a class, !myDiv results in a boolean (false or true) and again ! will reverse this boolean again (not resulting in the class instance (pointer)).

You also could write (myDiv != null).

Personally I prefer myDiv != null but !!myDiv is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

It's the double bang operator - it converts myDiv to a boolean value.